# Method defined in model not found by controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my controllers/tickets_controller.rb, I have:

```
def update
  @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  @ticket.save_customer_info_if_present(params, @ticket)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @ticket.update_attributes(params[:lead_billing])
      format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Ticket was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And in my models/ticket.rb, I have:

```
def self.save_customer_info_if_present(params, ticket)
  customer_info_params = params[:customer_info]
  if !customer_info_params.nil?
    customer_info = CustomerInfo.new(
        :ticket_id => ticket.id,
        :first => customer_info_params["first"],
        :last => customer_info_params["last"],
        :status => 'entered'
    )
    customer_info.save
  end
end
```

When the update action is run, I get an "method not found: save_customer_info_if_present"

Why isn't the controller finding the self method defined in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call a method on the instance of the model:

```
  @ticket.save_customer_info_if_present(params, @ticket)
```

But define this method as the class method:

```
def self.save_customer_info_if_present(params, ticket)
    # some code here
```

Remove the `self` keyword from the method definition, also you can remove a ticket argument because you already call this method on the ticket instance(make it more readable):

```
def save_customer_info_if_present(params)
  if params[:customer_info].present?
    customer_info = CustomerInfo.new(
        :ticket_id => id, # just an id because it in the ticket instance
        :first => params[:customer_info]["first"],
        :last => params[:customer_info]["last"],
        :status => 'entered'
    )
    customer_info.save
  end
end
```

<sub><sup>[Class and Instance Methods in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you. When I first write this, I was passing the ticket id only, and now I am passing @ticket, but forgot that it changed everything. The weird part, is that it was working for a while.